# App upgrade process gets stuck

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, timer-jobs, sharepoint-hosted-app

Im trying to update an existing Sharepoint-hosted App to a new version. I uploaded the new app-file to the app catalog and then clicked Update on my App information.

The text "We're updating your app" is now visible, just as usual. However, it never gets updated because the timer job gets stuck at 0 % and then quits without having updated the app. How can I troubleshoot this?

[image: App Installation Service stuck at 0 %]

Comment: Can you please check ULS logs, Event viewer for error details.

Comment: I find no real clues in ULS logs

Comment: OWSTIMER.EXE (0x9AEC)     App Deployment        Unexpected Exception while executing task 8e6fe2f0-2a73-4ec3-817d-ab56de443a4d of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPUserCodeSolutionDeploymentGroup in job 02210be9-969b-4f96-ba7e-b530d89597fb for instance f2a1b1e0-19bc-481d-80bc-f5f7dc8b6cae, rollback = False: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array.

Comment: Did you try troubleshooting it using the SharePoint logs ? did you try to check the status and errors of the timer job using PowerShell?